# Twitter API doesn't work in AJAX Success Call

Tags: ajax, django, twitter

Using Django, I'm building a search function that will subsequently display tweets.

Based on user input, the AJAX posts to views, which returns a list of ids that should be used to fetch tweets with the twitter API. When `twttr.widgets.createTweet()` is called in the AJAX success function, I get:

> Refused to execute script from https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/tweets.json?callback=__twttr.callbacks.cb0&ids=%2C%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined%2Cundefined&lang=en&suppress_response_codes=true&theme=light&tz=GMT-0400' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

The API call works perfectly when it's called `onLoad`.
I have confirmed that the success function fires. 
I've tried to change the AJAX datatype, which doesn't work.

Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype : "json",
        data: {
          'search': x,
        },
        success: function(data) {
           a = data
           genTweets(a)

      });
```

genTweets(which generates elements to populate with tweets):

```
function genTweets(a){
 if (a.length < 30){
 for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
          var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
          x = String(a[i])
          document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
          newDiv.id = "tweet" + i
          newDiv.setAttribute("tweetID", x)
          newDiv.setAttribute("class", "offset-3 col-8")
          genTweet(newDiv.id)
           }
           }
}
```

genTweet:

```
 genTweet = function(tweet){
    var tweet = document.getElementById(tweet);
    var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
     twttr.widgets.createTweet(
      id, tweet)
    }
```

Comment: can you share your view code too? is it working fine?

Comment: @AmanGarg I verified that the view works fine, it's just when I call twttr.widgets.createTweet() it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Running twttr.widgets.createTweet() with the data from the AJAX call was the issue, as the AJAX response was JSON.  This lead the ids to be undefined, and the API didn't like that. Using data.key as the parameter fixes it. Still unsure why this error is only thrown in the AJAX call, but it works now.